# Organize a Mysql Database by Lat/Long More

Tags: mysql, sql, gis

I need to organize a Mysql Database of 7,000,000 records. It needs to be queryable by a Lat/Long square, example: 22.54x -134.74x. It also needs to be broken down by `month` and `name`. There are about 700 possible names.

I have no clue how to manage all of this data so that someone within that lat/long square can quickly query only the `names` that exist inside that month and lat/long square.

Do I need 10,000+ tables for every lat/long possibility? Then from there broken down into months and names? My mind is about to explode.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL offers [spatial extensions that are specifically designed to efficiently deal with lat/long type problems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html).

If you use these extensions, a given row would contain the relevant latitude and longitude of a place, and the query would describe the geometric boundary that you are interested in.

Your query can look something along the lines of

```
SELECT name, AsText(location) FROM Points 
    WHERE X(location) > 0 AND X(location) < 1 AND
    Y(location) > 38 AND Y(location) < 39
```

This would select places whose location (location here is a spatial column in the database) has a longitude between 0 and 1, and a latitude between 38 and 39.

Comment: I've used this sort of stuff in the past, but the problem is I need the query to be in seconds, and going through 7 million records takes much longer. I was going to split the data into small lat/long squares, and based on the lat/long of the user, the query would run through a much smaller table(I guess).

Comment: I used PostreSQL spatial extensions for very large datasets and the queries were subsecond with proper indexing and hardware.  If you split into small squares, you have to do the overlap handling yourself.  That is not easy.  Back then (2009) I selected PostgreSQL over MySQL because the spatial extensions were more mature.  For point-in-rectangle, MySQL should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Eric. I just tried the query you put up above there and it was pretty great. It only took around 30 seconds. Any idea how to get that down to a second or two? It's a huge database!

Comment: What do your indices look like?  Sounds like you are doing a table scan.

Comment: As dumb as it sounds, I'm not really sure what indexes to use. I don't have any. The data never changes so indexes wouldn't be a problem, I just don't know what to index together.

Comment: @Patrick: Check out this info on how to create spatial indices: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-spatial-analysis.html

Answer (score 0):

For a modern database 7,000,000 rows are not much. If you use an index you will improve the access time significantly. Splitting the tables is not necessary. I have made experiments with mySQL and about 1 million locations and was not using the spatial extension and was happy with the access times (been still below 1 second).

You would do something like:

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx ON my_pos_table (month,name,lng,lat);
```

I suggest that you give it a try. There is nothing better than empirical information. Also observe how you access the data. Maybe you do not always access by month and name, so you can add more indicies, which will be only a disadvantage when inserting a row.

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx_2 ON my_pos_table (name,lng,lat);    
CREATE INDEX my_idx_3 ON my_pos_table (lng,lat);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will never be updating these tables, so will making a lot of indexes be the right idea?

Comment: @Patrick: MySQL will only ever use one index for a given query.  Since you don't incur the cost of updating the indices after initial creation, and given that disk space is cheap, having an index optimized for each major query is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a usefull post here:

http://blog.jcole.us/2007/11/24/on-efficiently-geo-referencing-ips-with-maxmind-geoip-and-mysql-gis/

I have used this post as a "starting point" for a project over 150milions of record -myisam- and it works fine

BTW, in general the best way is to use the `GEOMETRY` and `SPATIAL INDEX` -only for myisam- like as follow:

- `ALTER TABLE <table> ADD geom_point GEOMETRY NOT NULL ;`
- `ALTER TABLE <table> ADD SPATIAL INDEX geom_point (geom_point) ;`
- `UPDATE <table> SET geom_point = POINT(latitude, longitude);`

Now you can find all "names" into a "square" using a query like this:

```
SELECT * from <table> WHERE 
 MBRContains(GeomFromText('LineString(<lata> <lona>, <latb> <lonb>)'), geom_point)
```

Or by distance like:

```
$longitude = 8.449997;
$latitude = 45.550003;
$distance = 50; # km

$point1 = $latitude + $distance / ( 111.1 / cos($latitude));
$point2 = $longitude + $distance / 111.1;
$point3 = $latitude - $distance / ( 111.1 / cos($latitude));
$point4 = $longitude - $distance / 111.1;

SELECT * from <table> WHERE 
 MBRContains(GeomFromText('LineString(<$point1> <$point2>, <$point3> <$point4>)'), geom_point)
```

Try on your test table ;)